# Spring REST API :Returning a single int value?

Tags: rest

I have a Spring REST API That returns a just a int as a JSON , Do I need to create a Model, Or can just return something like 
return {"count" : 10}; //current doing this

I am thinking model is a overkill but not sure if my idea is bad design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A case can be made for both.  I would recommend a model because it leads to more reusable code and can better deal with future changes to this model.

Comment: I guess I will create a generic Model, that can be used for all the API 's in the project .